# Azure Durable Functions. Changing the hubName doesn't affect storage account tables

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying the specify task hub name for my durable function following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp#hostjson-functions-20-1).

Here are steps I've done:

**host.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "hubName": "%TaskHubName%"
        },
        // ...
    }
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "connection string",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "TaskHubName": "mytaskhub"
    }
    // ...
}
```

**MyFunction.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "foo/bar")]
            [RequestBodyType(typeof(List<QueryParams>), "Query Parameters")] HttpRequest req,
            [OrchestrationClient(TaskHub = "%TaskHubName%")] DurableOrchestrationClient starter)
```

However I don't see any changes in my Azure Storage Account after running this function. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you facing this during local debugging or in deployed Azure app?

Comment: I'm testing locally, but I set connection string to be pointing to Azure storage. When I used local storage emulator, nothing was happening either

Comment: In the Function Run method, you are passing `DurableOrchestrationClient starter`, is that a typo? In Function V2/3, it should be `IDurableOrchestrationClient starter` (interface). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I simply didn't update the tables list...everything is working, sorry for disruption.